# Bash 4.2 Associative arrays throws "bad array subscript" error

Tags: bash, associative-array, bash4

I'm trying to create this associative array, but it throws an error because of the `volumeClaimTemplates[0]`

This is my code:

```
declare -A example=(["'spec.statefulSet.spec.volumeClaimTemplates[0].spec'"]="TEST")
```

This is the error:

```
['spec.statefulSet.spec.volumeClaimTemplates[0].spec']=TEST: bad array subscript
```

If I remove the `[0]` from the `volumeClaimTemplates` then I get no errors.

Comment: Try escaping the square brackets - i.e. `\[0\]`.

Comment: Can't reproduce in bash 5.0.

Comment: Reproduces in `docker run bash:4.2`. I believe that in older bash versions array subscripts were restricted to some set of characters. @kooreshakhbari This is a question&answer forum. You asked no question in your post. In the spirit of this forum, could you add a question? Seems like `]` character is the problem - `declare -A a=(["]"]=1)`

Comment: Are you trying to simulate nested objects using associative arrays? Maybe you should use a language that already has them.

Comment: If I `printf %q\\n "'spec.statefulSet.spec.volumeClaimTemplates[0].spec'"` it outputs → `\'spec.statefulSet.spec.volumeClaimTemplates\[0\].spec\'`. I'd simply quote the associative array key the same way then: `declare -A example=([\'spec.statefulSet.spec.volumeClaimTemplates\[0\].spec\']="TEST")`

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work like this

```
declare -A example=(["spec.statefulSet.spec.volumeClaimTemplates[0\].spec.storageClassName"]="TEST"
```